# User.IsInRole("Admin") and everything related to it does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, roles

I'm trying to create authorization by roles (Admin\User) based on Cookies
Added Add Default Identity and enabled UseAuthentication and UseAuthorization
Authentication works, .net sees roles from the database, but does not let either the user or the administrator into User.IsInRole("Admin")

The field data is taken from the Users table, where there is a role field and

class Program

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Services.AddDbContext<StoreContext>();
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();


    builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<StoreContext>();

    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
        });

    builder.Services.AddAuthentication();
    builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

    var app = builder.Build();

    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    app.Run();
}
```

AccountController

```
private StoreContext _storeContext;
public AccountController(StoreContext context)
{
    _storeContext = context;
}

[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public IActionResult a()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Register()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        User user = await _storeContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == model.Email);

        if (user == null)
        {
            user = new User { Email = model.Email, Password = model.Password, Adress = model.Adress, Phone = model.Phone, Name = model.Name };

            if (user != null)
            {
                _storeContext.Users.Add(user);

                await _storeContext.SaveChangesAsync();

                await Authenticate(user);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Некорректные логин и(или) пароль");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Некорректные логин и(или) пароль");
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LogInModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        User user = await _storeContext.Users
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == model.Email && u.Password == model.Password);

        if (user != null)
        {
            await Authenticate(user); 

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Некорректные логин и(или) пароль");
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
private async Task Authenticate(User user)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, user.Email),
        new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, user.Role)
    };

    ClaimsIdentity id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "ApplicationCookie", ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType,
        ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
    
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(id));
}
```

Views index

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>

    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <p>@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated</p>
        <p>@User.Identity.AuthenticationType</p>
        <p>@User.Identity.Name</p>
        <p>admin - @User.IsInRole("Admin")</p>
    }
    else
    {
        <a class="register" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" style="color: black">Регистрация</a>
        <a class="login" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogIn" style="color: black">Вход</a>
    }

    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        <a style="color: green">admin</a>
    }
    else if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("User"))
    {
        <a style="color: red">user</a>
    }

</div>
```

If you register in HomeController

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    string role = User.FindFirst(x => x.Type == ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType).Value;

    return Content($"ваша роль: {role}");

    //return View();
}
```

Then it outputs the role

[image]

But it doesn't go to User.IsInRole("Admin")

[image]

I tried to find a solution to the problem, but I didn't find it. Please help.

Comment: Do you set a breakpoint at `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)` to see the claims ?

Comment: Please check if you spelled Admin exactly like that in your roles. IdentityRole.Name needs to match with the argument to `IsInRole()` case-wise.

Comment: What's your `Users` table  ? How do you define your Role ?

Comment: I test your code, the result like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7BXo.png

Comment: @user:17124525 did you do everything exactly like mine? I define the user role in the User table

Comment: Yes, I do everything exactly like yours: this is my user table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PuOJ.png

Comment: If you can build a small demo and share it via gihub , so that we can test it, we'll be better able to help you.

Comment: @user:17124525 it's strange why it doesn't work for me then (Yes, I can share the broadcast, only I've never worked with it. I will be very grateful to you)

Comment: @user:17124525 git: https://github.com/abobinad/store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> entity.Property(e => e.Role)
> .IsRequired()
> .HasMaxLength(10)
> .IsFixedLength()
> .HasColumnName("role");

Because you configures the property to be fixed length by  `.HasMaxLength(10).IsFixedLength()`, when you add `Admin` in your database, it will add white-space to meet the length. Then your user data (Authenticate(User user)) get from your database will be`"Admin  "` ,so when you use `@User.IsInRole("Admin")` is false.

You can try to remove white-space by `.Trim()` ,
try:

```
new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, user.Role.Trim())
```

result:

[image]